# "Failed to perform Visit End actions" error in 6.6

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Sitecore 6.6

I'm getting the following messages in my log files after a new site went live on our Sitecore instance:

```
19224 10:04:41 ERROR Failed to perform Visit End actions
Exception: System.InvalidCastException
Message: Unable to cast object of type 'Sitecore.Web.SessionEndWorkerRequest' to type 'System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest'
```

Other sites that have already been live for some time have not shown these error messages.

We have a single CM server with two, separate CD servers that do not have access to the `master` database.

In researching the error, a lot of people mention that you have to remove references to the `master` database, but I don't have any as far as I can tell.  I have utilized the "SwitchMasterToWeb.config" file.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I may have resolved this. (or at least suppressed the error)  It turns out that only one of the CDs was reporting this error.  Upon further investigation, the reporting CD had an additional "traceFailedRequests" entry under "system.webServer" in the web.config.  I removed this section and haven't seen the error again.  Would still be interested if something is broken and not working.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably forgotten about this by now, but since you said you would be interested...

It looks like the error message `Failed to perform Visit End actions` error would come from an exception in the visitEnd pipeline normally configured in your Sitecore.Analytics.config file.  I'm not sure why the failed request tracing would have any effect on this.  Check the following:

- Do you have any custom processors for the visitEnd pipeline?
- Do you have custom rules defined under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Rules/Session End/Rules`?
- Do you have a rule defined on the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Session End` item?

If things appear normal there, I would think you're safe.

Comment: +1  Thanks!  Yeah, nothing custom with the visitEnd pipeline or rules.  Haven't seen any ill effects.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but might be help full for other because same issue also exist in current version as well.

```
ERROR Failed to perform Visit End actions 
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException 
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master'] 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel 
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String message) 
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert) 
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) 
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name) 
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunRules.Process(VisitEndArgs endArgs) 
   at (Object , Object[] ) 
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) 
   at Sitecore.Analytics.VisitEndWorker.Helper.Process(Action visitEndAction)
```

To fix this, you'll need to create a new file named Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultDefinitionDatabase.config with the following configs added to it:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="Analytics.DefaultDefinitionDatabase">
                <patch:attribute name="value">web</patch:attribute>
            </setting>
        </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** 
This setting is currently not located in any file, it's hard-coded into the Analytics DLL and the default value for this setting is "master", therefore, you MUST create a new config file to override this setting.
If you still get the error, there may be more references to master in the config files that were added after the standard install.  Two examples are the News Mover module and Advanced Database Crawler.  The solution is to find all references to these master databases and patch them to replace with web or remove the setting entirely if it is not needed in the context of a delivery server.

Ref: http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/MarkGraber/2013/June/Tips-on-Setting-up-a-Content-Delivery-Server-with-No-Master-Database.aspx